# django making deeper static root on every deploy

Tags: django

I have django setup to set the static root inside a static folder in the project directory, but every time I deploy it is adding another layer of root folders for the static files. I can't figure out why this is happenning...

```
+ project
  -app1
  +static
    +root
      +root
        +root
         +root
  -templates
  -manage.py
```

Here is the settings for static...

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'root')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    )

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'main', 'static')
)
```

AND NGINX...

```
# your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/langalang/static/root;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your static root is included in your staticfiles_dirs, so every time Django runs collectstatic it puts it inside itself. Don't do that: keep them separate.